# What is the best way to call Java code from Python?

Tags: java, python

I have a Java class library (3rd party, proprietary) and I want my python script to call its functions. I already have java code that uses this library. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438594/how-to-call-java-objects-and-functions-from-cpython, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201628/java-wrapper-to-perl-python-code

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Can you run your current Python scripts under [Jython](http://www.jython.org) ? If so, that's probably the best way, since the Java library can be exposed directly into Jython as scriptable objects.

Failing that, there are a number of solutions listed [here](http://wiki.cacr.caltech.edu/danse/index.php/Communication_between_Java_and_Python).

Comment: If using scipy and numpy, Jython may not be an option.

Answer (score 8):

The other answer is [JPype](http://jpype.sourceforge.net/), which allows CPython to talk to Java. It's useful if you can't switch to Jython.

Answer (score 3):

There's also [JCC](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/jcc/index.html) which is not mentioned on the Caltech page.

Quote:

> JCC is a C++ code generator that
>   produces a C++ object interface
>   wrapping a Java library via Java's
>   Native Interface (JNI). JCC also
>   generates C++ wrappers that conform to
>   Python's C type system making the
>   instances of Java classes directly
>   available to a Python interpreter.
>
> When generating Python wrappers, JCC
>   produces a complete Python extension
>   via the distutils or setuptools
>   packages.